# How do I correctly map versioned resources in Grails?

Tags: rest, grails

I have grails running a REST API and using version numbers in the URL like so: `https://api.mycompany.com/v2/metadata`. I need to change the parameters of one of the endpoints, so I'm bumping the version up to `v3`. Only one controller is affected, so I would like to delegate the remaining calls back to the controllers for `v2` without having to copy/paste everything again. Here's the relevant section of my `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/v3/widget"(controller: "v3widget")
        "/v3/$otherResource" {
            // does not work, but illustrates what I want to happen
            uri = { "/v2/" + params.otherResource }
        }


        // rest of my file...
        "/v2/metadata"(controller: 'metadata')
...
```

What's the correct way to do this? I'm using grails 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found that works relies on the fact that wildcard mappings can also accept other regular expressions:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        // v3 specific
        "/v3/widget"(controller: "v3widget")
        // v3/v2 common
        "/v[23]/$otherResource" {
            // normal mappings go here
        }
        // v2 specific
        "/v2/metadata"(controller: 'v2metadata')
...
```

This solution works well since I don't have to repeat any mappings, and it's clear what's different between v2 and v3 resources.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a variable in the uri path, and instead of your example you would have the following mappings:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/$apiVersion/widget"(controller: "v3widget")
        "/$apiVersion/otherResource"(controller: "otherResource")
        // rest of my file...
        "/$apiVersion/metadata"(controller: 'metadata')
...
```

And then you could check for the value in controller:

```
class OtherResourceController {

    def index(){
        if(params.apiVersion == 'v2') {
          ...
        } else {
          ...
        }
    }

}
```

The example here is checking for the string value, but you could go a bit deeper and actually convert the string value into internal api version enum representation which might be easier to manage. You could also do that in filter.

This way you can increment the logic changes and api will have a nice fallback, will delegate to default version.

But it gets really curly when you have couple of api versions layered one on the other.